# Align logo in the footline with the ones in the header in beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, footer

I am using a template from overleaf:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/yet-another-beamerposter-theme-with-variable-sizes-and-colour-themes-landscape/tcwvmhjsfbdk

I did a few changes and I came to this LLTposter-sample.tex code:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    %% Possible paper sizes: a0, a0b, a1, a2, a3, a4.
    %% Possible orientations: portrait, landscape
    %% Font sizes can be changed using the scale option.
    \usepackage[size=a3,orientation=landscape,scale=1.8]{beamerposter}
    \usetheme{LLT-poster}
    % \usecolortheme{ComingClean}
    \usecolortheme{Entrepreneur}
    % \usecolortheme{ConspiciousCreep}  %% VERY garish.
    
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{libertine}
    \usepackage[scaled=0.92]{inconsolata}
    \usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
    
    \usepackage{mwe}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    
    
    %\author[liantze@gmail.com]{Lim Lian Tze}
    %\title{Yet Another beamerposter Theme\\(Variable Sizes and Colour Themes)}
    %\institute{Your Institution}
    % Optional foot image
    \footimage{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-duck}\hspace{3cm}\mbox{}}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \input{slide_1/slide_1}
    
    
    \end{document}
```

Here is the slide_1 code:

```
\author[school]{department}
\title{Title\\(subtitle)}
\institute{Location (city)}
% Optional foot image

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%HEADLINE COPIATA E INCOLLATA
\begin{comment}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
 \leavevmode
  \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{.1\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}
   \end{column}
   \begin{column}{.8\linewidth}
    %\vskip0.5cm
    \centering
    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}%{\color{jblue}\Large{\textbf{\inserttitle}}\\[0.5ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}%{\color{fg}\normalsize{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}%{\color{fg}\small{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}
    %\vskip0.5cm
   \end{column}
   \begin{column}{.1\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}
   \end{column}
   %\vspace{1cm}
  \end{columns}
 %\vspace{0.5in}
 %\hspace{0.5in}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=47in,colsep=0.15cm]{cboxb}\end{beamercolorbox}
 %\vspace{0.1in}
}
\end{comment}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{columns}[T]

%%%% First Column
\begin{column}{.33\textwidth}

\begin{block}{Abstract}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is the template I created for my poster presentations.
\item You can provide an optional \verb|\footimage|.
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Options}
\begin{itemize}
\item It's based on \texttt{beamerposter}, so you can change some options:
  \begin{description}
  \item[size] a0, a0b, a1, a2, a3, a4
  \item[orientiation] landscape, portrait
  \item[scale] a decimal number to scale the fonts
  \end{description}
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Colour Themes}
\begin{itemize}
\item I've included some colour themes, using the colour palettes from \url{http://colourlovers.com}
\begin{itemize}
\item ComingClean (teak and cream)
\item Entrepreneur (current theme)
\item Conspicious (a bit garish!)
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\end{column}

%%%% Second Column
\begin{column}{.3\textwidth}

\begin{block}{This is a sample}
\begin{itemize}
\item One, two, pick up my shoe
\item Three, four, shut the door
\item Five, six, pick up sticks
\item Seven, eight, lay them straight
\item Nine, ten, a big fat hen
\item One, two, pick up my shoe
\item Three, four, shut the door
\item Five, six, pick up sticks
\item Seven, eight, lay them straight
\item Nine, ten, a big fat hen
\end{itemize}
\end{block}


\begin{block}{This is another sample}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some maths material
\begin{align}
A &= U \times S \times V^T\\
\sigma &= \frac{x\times y}{\sqrt[3]{\alpha + \beta}}
\end{align}
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{column}

%%%% This is the THIRD column
\begin{column}{.33\textwidth}
\begin{block}{Brighten it up!}
This particular colour theme could do with some colourful images to brighten it up -- go wild with your charts!

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-grid-100x100bp}
\end{center}

\end{block}
\end{column}

\end{columns}

\begin{block}{This is a sample of a wiiiide column}
\begin{itemize}
\item One, two, pick up my shoe
\item Three, four, shut the door
\item Five, six, pick up sticks
\item Seven, eight, lay them straight
\item Nine, ten, a big fat hen
\end{itemize}
\end{block}


\end{frame}
```

And here the beamerthemeLLT-poster.sty file I am using:

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\footimage}[1]{\def\footim@ge{#1}}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth]{headline}
     \vskip2em\centering
     \parbox{.1\linewidth}{\hspace{.1\linewidth}\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}%
     \parbox{.8\linewidth}{\normalbaselines\centering\usebeamercolor{title in headline}\color{fg}{\bfseries\rmfamily\huge\inserttitle}}%
    \parbox{.1\linewidth}{\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-duck}\hspace{.1\linewidth}}%
     \vskip2em
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line head}
    \rule{0pt}{1em}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\setbeamerfont{structure}{series=\bf,family=\sffamily,size=\Large}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\vspace*{-1ex}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body end}{\vspace*{-0.5ex}}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{$\blacktriangleright\,$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{$\bullet$ }
\setlength\leftmargini{3.5em}

\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{
  \vskip.75ex
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=1em,colsep*=.75ex]{block title}%
    \usebeamerfont{block title}\insertblocktitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,sep=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
  }
\setbeamertemplate{block end}{
  \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip1ex
}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\small,family=\rmfamily}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{upper separation line foot}
    \rule{0pt}{.5em}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{footline}
     \vskip1.5ex
     \hspace{1em}\usebeamercolor{author in footline}{\bfseries\large\insertauthor}\par\vskip1ex
     \hspace{1em}{\small\ttfamily\bfseries\insertshortauthor}\par\vskip.8ex
     \hspace{1em}\usebeamercolor{institute in footline}{\color{fg}\small\bfseries\insertinstitute}\vskip1ex
   \end{beamercolorbox}
   
%
\ifdefined\footim@ge
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]%
  \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.south east) %
  {\footim@ge};
\fi
}
```

Is there a way I can aling all the 3 logo like in the picture, and clean a little bit the code, maybe putting the instruction for the logos in the .sty file or in the beamerthemeLLT-poster.sty?[image]

Comment: You could at least attempt to change the 3cm to something you like :( Also splitting your code into even more fragments does not make it more convenient to answer your questions.

Comment: ... also why did you ask how to add logos to the headline, if you have code to do so in `slide_1.tex`?

Comment: because it doesn't show up when I compile

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` from the `.sty` file. They don't belong in a `.sty` file, and especially the `\makeatother` causes the `\ifdefined\footim@ge` to fail.

And if you want the logo in the corner, remove the `\hspace{3cm}`.